# Gridview or Listview to display 3 columns with many rows

Tags: android, android-layout, android-listview, android-gridview

How would you make the following user interface (see the picture below)?

The UI always has 3 columns, and many rows.
Pressing any button1 saves the data of its respective row in memory.
Pressing any button2 deletes the data in its respective row.

I am still undecided between a gridview and a listview, and quite confused how to code at this time (in particular the onClicklistener). Thank you in advance for any help.

[image: I am planning to use]

Comment: use a table layout for this.

Comment: depends on how many rows you have ... if less than 10(just an example) then maybe table layout ... for more ListView(remeber to use convertView in adapter) ... TableLayout will be unefficient for lots of data

Comment: Did you create row dynamically or use static row ?

Comment: The number of rows vary based on the user input, and are known by the time this page is loaded.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use a listview with a custom list item which has a linearlayout with the other views inside

custom list tutorials:

http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidListView/article.html

http://www.androidhive.info/2012/02/android-custom-listview-with-image-and-text/

example custom list item:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/layout1"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/layout2"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/layout2"
    android:text="Data: " 
    android:gravity="center|left"
    android:textSize="16sp"/>

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/layout2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Button" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button2"
        style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Button" />
</LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use a table layout for such look and feel. see [this](http://www.mkyong.com/android/android-tablelayout-example/) example .and [this](http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/An_Android_TableLayout_and_TableRow_Tutorial) also.

Table layout is useful because you can define easily how many columns and rows you want in your view. and after then you can easily place widgets in that.

Comment: because he should use listview

Comment: post the reason with an answer. i will then delete my answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
// Try this way,hope this will help you to solve your problem...

Note : i think you have to use "ListView" with custom adapter.,"ListView" more convenient for less or more no data.

**list_item.xml**

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="0.50"
        android:gravity="center_vertical">
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textview"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Data"/>
    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0.50">
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button1"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="Button1"/>
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button2"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="Button2"/>
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```